# Matrix from rows with delimited items in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a such database with semicolon delimited values in rows:

```
A;1;3;5;7;9
B;1;2;3
C;1;3;5
D;2;4;8
```

There is different count of items in each row. Each item is only once in each row (no repeating).

I'd like to make a matrix for item base collaborative filtering. The first column with letters is deleted and the numbers are transformed like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
-----------------
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Can you please give me an advice how to manage it?

Comment: are you looking for [table](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/table) ?

Comment: Pretty sure this has been asked and answered many times (not that I would necessarily have been able to find it with a search). Basic paradigm is stack the input to build a two-column matrix as index to "[<-".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option.  We read in the string into a character vector, `strsplit` on `;`, initialize the empty matrix, and then assign for each row using a matrix index of the row with all the column values:

```
DAT <- readLines(textConnection("A;1;3;5;7;9
B;1;2;3
C;1;3;5
D;2;4;8"))

DAT.NUM <- lapply(strsplit(DAT, ";"), function(x) as.integer(x[-1]))
RES <- matrix(0L, length(DAT), max(unlist(DAT.NUM)))
for(i in seq_along(DAT)) RES[cbind(i, DAT.NUM[[i]])] <- 1L
```

Produces:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1
[2,]    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    1    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    0
```

Alternatively, inspired by @user227710, you can:

```
t(table(stack(setNames(DAT.NUM, seq_along(DAT.NUM)))))
```

Which produces:

```
   values
ind 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9
  1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1
  2 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
  3 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
  4 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
```